# Connecting laptop to Raspberry Pi with Node server

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a web app running on a Node.js server on a Raspberry Pi. I can use my MacBook to connect to the WiFi for the Raspberry Pi only if the MacBook is plugged into an internet connection through an ethernet cable as well.

If an ethernet cable is plugged into my MacBook and then the other end is connected to LAN, I can use my WiFi to connect to the RPi, but as soon as I disconnect my ethernet cable from the MacBook, I cannot connect to the RPi via WiFi. How can I start troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: try `traceroute` to display the route (path) across your IP network in both scenarios.

Comment: I tried doing a tracert on the IP, and it resolves just fine. I can tracert the domain and IP. I can ping the domain and IP. The nslookup of the domain resolves to the right IP. IPCONFIG shows that the device connecting to the Raspberry Pi is handing out a similar IP address, so DHCP seems to work. Apparently, it is an issue with Raspberry Pi failing to initiate DNSMASQ.

Comment: Alright, tried applying a patch to DNSMASQ, restarted the service, and I'm still having the same issues. Tracert is behaving as expected, resolving the domain to the device's IP aadress.